# MultiQ in DPDK is configure "max_rx_queue=1" issue

Tags: dpdk

i need help regarding enabling multiQ (multiple queue ) for port in DPDK testpmd , when i use in command like --rxq=2 or --txq=N , it shows max_rx_queue =1 and i am not able to configure for more queue . please help me how can i configure multiple queue .

Comment: setting multiple queues depends upon NIC and PMD. are you running on Vm with 1 RX ?

Comment: yes i am running on virtual box with one RX queue , but not able to increase that queue number for ports , so that i can send data between ports throught multiple queue

Comment: I am not aware of the changes to be done in virtulbox (either in options or source code) to support this feature. But if you are using kvm-qemu `<interface type='vhostuser'>
<mac address='00:00:00:00:00:01'/>
<source type='unix' path='/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/dpdkvhostuser0' mode='client'/>
<model type='virtio'/>
<driver queues='2'>
<host mrg_rxbuf='off'/>
</driver>
</interface>`

Comment: were you able to figure out how to change the queues in virtual box?

Comment: For better reach in the community question had been edited to reflect the `true problem faced in enabling multi-q support for virtual-box`. But both https://stackoverflow.com/users/2080848/duck and https://stackoverflow.com/users/5123537/martin-bri%c5%a1iak rejects the changes stating `This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.`

Answer (score 0):

one can modify kvn-qemu either in cmdline or XML to reflect the desired number of virtio queues.

XML:
`<interface type='vhostuser'> <mac address='00:00:00:00:00:01'/> <source type='unix' path='/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/dpdkvhostuser0' mode='client'/> <model type='virtio'/> <driver queues='2'> <host mrg_rxbuf='off'/> </driver> </interface>`

P.S.: based on the update from the comment the VM environment is hosted over Virtualbox. Request for an update.

Comment: @arpitGupta have you checked your setup to enable multi-q?